# Specflow:Error:Result collection has not started in test explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit, appium, specflow

[image]

Working with specflow latest version, When I run my scripts I get result set cannot be started and been at this for a week. the automation script run to completion but it bring up this error and test fails .The specflow version 3.1.97 is and visual studio is 2019 . I have narrowed it down to a simple test and still fails , it seems to have something to do with specflow. I do not want to have to create a new solution and start again and I have wrote a lot of tests but cannot go any further as reports will always fail due to this error. I have checked online . I have tried different solution including https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/issues/1851 etc but to no avail.I have gone down version of specflow, specfow.tools.MsBuild.Generation ,nunit but still the same. If I create a new solution and add these dependencies it seems to be fine and do a quick test is works fine.

Feature file:

```
@Settings About
Scenario: About Screen
    Given user is already logged in
```

Step definition:

```
[Given(@"user is already logged in")]
public void GivenUserIsAlreadyLoggedIn()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(true);
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include your code. Please also note which version of SpecFlow and Visual Studio you have.

Comment: Hi, I have added information,  The code run to completion and then when testscript finished it appears with this error  This is a code snippet but they code would be a lot to give you @Settings About
Scenario: About Screen
 #Given user is already logged in 
 When user login with the following profile 
 | ClientCode | UserName | PassWord |

Comment: I can't read the code you posted in a comment. Please [edit] your question, add the code and format it using the format code icon in the question text toolbar.

Comment: I have narrowed it down to the basic where it is simply just calling  a simple assert and it still come up with this error, I have not a clue where to begin. I have installed nunit, speclow and appium it looks like specflow is giving some type of problem

Comment: See here for similar errors https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+collection+started

Comment: thanks it does not give any solution though just issue but thanks for getting back to me

Comment: Which version of the SpecFlow extension for Visual Studio do you want? Also, which *specific* version of VS 2019 do you have (e.g. v16.2)?

Comment: Specflow extension version is 2019.0.46.15077

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 16.62#

Comment: Specflow version 3.1.97

Comment: SpecFlow nunit 3.1.97

Answer (score 0):

I received this error message after moving my feature file into a shared assembly.  The reason for the error was that the static initialization methods generated by SpecFlow.MSBuild was not being called at startup. I fixed by chaining the call from the corresponding initialization method in the top level test assembly.

Although the reason for your problem is probably different, I suspect you can diagnose the problem using the same process.

- In the obj folder of your test project there should be a file called  MsTest.AssemblyHooks.cs.  Move this file into the main project folder and include in the project.
- Add the following xml into the csproj project file. (This turns off automatic hooks file generation).

  ```
  <PropertyGroup>
      <GenerateSpecFlowAssemblyHooksFile>false</GenerateSpecFlowAssemblyHooksFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  ```

You can then put a break point on the initialization code and debug. (You may be getting exceptions, or the initialization may not be being called.)

Note - you may be able to debug the initialization code in place without moving.  In my case I needed to modify the code, hence a permanent non-generated version.

For anyone else trying to split the feature file into a shared project, you also need to update app.config with

```
<configSections>
    <section name="specFlow" type="TechTalk.SpecFlow.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionHandler, TechTalk.SpecFlow">
 <configSections>
 <specFlow>
   <stepAssemblies>
     <stepAssembly assembly="[TODO - SharedAssemblyName]" />
   <stepAssemblies>
 </specFlow>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. However after a pure uninstall all Specflow related packages, then reinstall everything, it works fine? Go figure~ I'm testing 3.1.97 now. Once stable I'll try to 3.3.

Get rid of everything in your solution that uses or requires Specflow, then reinstall each package from scratch.